# Maintain relationship in new core data entry crash - swift

Tags: swift, core-data

I can input and create relationships in my current core data model. The issue I am having is trying to create a relationship with an existing attribute.

I figure I need to find the existing `NSManagedObject` and see if it is 0 (empty) or > 0 (already exists).

I am doing that but I get a bad access crash (I think due to my optionals) when trying to create a global reference to the NSManagedObject so I can pass it down the line for when I create the relationship.  What am I doing wrong? This is the way I have previously approached it in Obj-C.

```
   var visitEntityObject : NSManagedObject!
   var VisitsEntity = visitEntityObject as! VisitDetails //Crash

                    var resultsVisit:NSArray? = self.managedObjectContext!.executeFetchRequest(requestVisit, error: errorVisit)

                    if errorVisit != nil
                    {
                        println("Error: \(errorVisit.debugDescription)")
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        if resultsVisit?.count == 0
                        {

                            VisitsEntity = NSEntityDescription.insertNewObjectForEntityForName(visitEntityName, inManagedObjectContext: self.managedObjectContext!) as! VisitDetails

                            visitFound = false
                            println("Visit Not Found")
                        }
                        else
                        {

                            VisitsEntity = resultsVisit?.lastObject as! VisitDetails

                            visitFound = true
                            println("Visit Found")

                        }
                    }
```

[image]

```
fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value
```

Comment: It would help if you mark the line where the crash happens and add the full crash message.

Comment: I have marked the crash line. It is a bad access error.

Comment: Please add the full error message.

Comment: Is my logic sound when approaching this core data issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You declare an implicitly unwrapped optional

`var visitEntityObject : NSManagedObject!`

with no value and then proceed to use it without giving it a value. You can get away with this in Obj-C as it's much less strict around `nil`. This is just wrong in Swift - you should probably take another look at optionals and forced unwrapping the in the Swift guide to get a better understanding of what is wrong

Comment: I was aware this was the issue but I couldn't find how to state a NSManagedObject without inserting a value

Comment: You either need to create and insert a new managed object or fetch one. Either way you should not be implicitly unwrapping you should handle `nil` correctly

Comment: Yeah the issue I'm trying to overcome is to make the fetched NSManagedObject accesible down the line hence my attempt to make a global variable.

Comment: I'll mark this as correct as it is - just doesn't help me with my problem (which I think I explained badly)